# clustered hash map

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, cluster-computing

I have a Java application running in clustered hardware. I use Hashmap as cache. I want cache to be clustered also.  Are there some open source java project to synchronize Hashmap in two connected machine?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on Hazelcast ( http://www.hazelcast.com/ ). It has distributed maps and it is free and OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ehcache, it's available as Open source and with some license also.
Besides you can try using Toolkit from terracotta, which provides clustered DS like map,set,sortedmap,sortedset etc. For more info goto Terracotta's website.

Comment: Could we please have a link to the website?

Comment: Above link was for ehcache, here it one for [Toolkit](http://terracotta.org/documentation/bigmemorymax/terracotta-toolkit/toolkit-intro)